# Is there a way to see how many times a question has been viewed on iOS app?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, ios-app

When I access Stack Exchange in my browser, there's a helpful stat on the top right of the page that states how many times a question has been viewed. This stat is helpful because it tells the asker if people are reading and considering their question.

However, I can't seem to find where this stat is located in Stack Exchange's iOS app. Is there a place I can see how many times my question has been viewed from the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible within the app itself. The only, very convoluted, way is to open the question in the browser, by clicking the More button and selecting Open in Safari. The mobile website doesn't show the number of views either, but in the footer, there is a 'full site' link which takes you to the full site.

While the number of views is a nice statistic, it isn't that important and as always in mobile apps, we have less room to display information so something's gotta give.

[image]

---

[image]